# mstest (VS2013) crashes qtagent32 with .NET 3.5 unit test project

Tags: c#, mstest

I can't get mstest.exe in Visual Studio 2013 to work with a unit test project that targets the 3.5 framework.

Here is my reproduction plan:

1. Create a new C# unit test project in VS2013 that targets the 3.5 program.  I call the project MsTest35Eg.
2. Code the default TestMethod1 function with a simple assert: Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
3. Build
4. Test from within VS2013 (works fine)
5. Test with mstest using the following command:

   Set testRunnercmd="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
   %testRunnercmd% /testcontainer:"C:\Path\MsTest35Eg\bin\Debug\MsTest35Eg.dll"

When running this from the command line a window pops up and reports that qtagent32 has stopped working.

If I change the target framework to 4.0, then this works fine.  Unfortunately upgrading to this in my production test projects isn't an option.

I have an old copy of VS2008 on my machine.  If I use the v9.0 of mstest this works fine.  However, I don't want to have to continue to install VS2008 to support my test suite.

Can anyone explain or solve why mstest v12 can't seem to run v3.5 framework tests?